# Changing color of buttons with onclick events

Tags: android, button, gridview, onclick, baseadapter

I'm trying to create a Grid with 100 buttons, and a custom color selector. When i click a random button, it should change its' background into the selected color. Unfortunately I'm stuck on the following:

[MainActivity:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CBZn.png)
I'm not sure how to automate the onclick event for every button seperately, as the onclick function doesn't recognise which button is clicked in the inner class.

I'm using a gridview with a custom adapter:

[Adapter:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYJjE.png)
The adapter implemented in my Gridview -->  linearlayout.pixel is the xml file for my button.

Code linearlayout.pixel:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:id="@+id/grid_button"
    />
```

code drawable my_button:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="3dp" />
<stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.grid_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
       button.setBackgroundColor("#4FC3F7");
   }
};
```

Comment: Good luck bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  buttons[i]=new Button(this);
    buttons.setId(i);
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
           buttons[view.getId()].setBackgroundColor(color);
       }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, unfortunately this did not work for some reason.. The problem is fixed though, still I'm grateful for taking your time to answer me.